# JavaScript calculations return NaN as result

Tags: javascript, forms, nan

I am developing a html page that takes date and displays day. I am using a formula called Zeller's congruence. But in JavaScript the formula returns the Result "NaN". I googled the problem. Couldn't figure out the solution. 
Here is the html that takes values.

```
<form method="post">
<br/>
day:<input id="dd" name="dd" type="text"/><br/>
month:<input id="mm" name="mm" type="text"/><br/>
year:<input id="yy" name="yy" type="text"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="go" onclick="day()"/><br/>
</form>
```

Here is the piece of JavaScript formula thats returning NaN.

```
function day() { 
var d=document.getElementById("dd").value;
var m=document.getElementById("mm").value;
var y=document.getElementById("yy").value;

var h=(d+(((m+1)*26)/10)+y+(y/4)+6*(y/100)+(y/400))%7;//returns NaN
var d2=((h+5)%7); code continues..
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert the `d`, `m`, and `y` to numbers first (`.value` returns a string). In some scenarios in your math, string concatenation might be happening instead of addition. In my console, I get a decimal number when `d`, `m`, and `y` are numbers, and `NaN` when they are strings. Converting them to numbers is as simple as `var d = +document.getElementById("dd").value;` for example

Comment: thank you. thank worked perfectly.

Comment: Pro debugging tip:  If you add the line `console.log([d, m, y]);` you could have seen the values for all three variables and the quotes would have told you they were strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases `+` signs in your formula will do string concatenation instead of sum, as in JavaScript `"1" + 1 === "11"`. You need to convert your values from strings (as returned from form fields) to numbers with `parseInt` or `parseFloat` functions:

```
var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("dd").value, 10);
```

or to support float numbers (if required):

```
var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("dd").value);
```

or a shortcut of `Number(v)`:

```
var d = +document.getElementById("dd").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Convert your values into numbers for use parseInt();

  <script>
  function day() { 
  var D=document.getElementById("dd").value;
  var M=document.getElementById("mm").value;
  var Y=document.getElementById("yy").value;

  var d=parseInt(D);
  var m=parseInt(M);
  var y= parseInt(Y);

  var h=(d+(((m+1)*26)/10)+y+(y/4)+6*(y/100)+(y/400))%7;

  alert(h);
 }
</script>

<form method="post">
 <br/>
 day:<input id="dd" name="dd" type="text"/><br/>
 month:<input id="mm" name="mm" type="text"/><br/>
 year:<input id="yy" name="yy" type="text"/><br/>
 <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="day()"/><br/>
 </form>
```