# How to Get the Result Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working with this code and would like to get the result inside `intTotal`. But it doesn't give me the result I wish.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var intNum = document.getElementById("intNum");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3000; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = i;
    option.value = i;
    intNum.appendChild(option);
  }
};

function jml_total() {
  var hrg_sat = parseInt(document.querySelector("hrg_sat").innerHTML);
  var jml_pilih = parseInt(document.getElementById("intNum").value);
  var int_hitung = hrg_sat * jml_pilih;
  document.getElementById("intTotal").value = int_hitung;
}
```

```html
<div id="hrg_sat">3000</div>
<select id="intNum" onChange="jml_total(this.value)">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Jumlah ... </option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="intTotal"></div>
```

I tried this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999132/javascript-calculations-return-nan-as-result). Or, you have the simplest one, but not using jquery.

Comment: The `select` doesn't have any numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that `hrg_sat` is an id on your `querySelector` by using `#` as prefix

```
var hrg_sat = parseInt(document.querySelector("#hrg_sat").innerHTML);
```

Also, as the previous answer has mentioned, you need to use `innerHTML` property instead of `value` to display the text on the DOM on a `<div>` element

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var intNum = document.getElementById("intNum");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3000; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = i;
    option.value = i;
    intNum.appendChild(option);
  }
};

function jml_total() {
  var hrg_sat = parseInt(document.querySelector("#hrg_sat").innerHTML);
  var jml_pilih = parseInt(document.getElementById("intNum").value);
  var int_hitung = hrg_sat * jml_pilih;
  document.getElementById("intTotal").innerHTML = int_hitung;
}
```

```html
<div id="hrg_sat">3000</div>
<select id="intNum" onChange="jml_total(this.value)">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Jumlah ... </option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="intTotal"></div>
```

Comment: hehe .. really helps. two nights, solved 100%. using `#hrg_sat`. Let me know, why using `#hrg_sat` ?

Comment: You are using the document [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors). The `#` is necessary in order for you to specify that it is an `id` attribute. You could, alternatively, use `document.getElementById("hrg_sat")` instead if you are sure that you are selecting an Id

Answer (score 0):

Since `intTotal` is a div, you want to use `innerHTML` not `value`. `value` in the post you linked to is for an input control, not a div

```js
document.getElementById("intTotal").innerHTML = 'your content goes here';
```

```html
<div id="intTotal"></div>
```

Comment: Did you check the console? There is an error. @95faf8e76605e973 already posted a working example but you can also use `document.getElementById("hrg_sat")` instead of`document.querySelector`